# How to create a link dynamically to a function

Tags: c#, html, dynamic, hyperlink

I have a list stored as objects. On the page, the contents of the list are displayed when a linkbutton is clicked. Each list item is displayed as a row with a "VIEW" link that when clicked will call a function in the code behind to display further content. How do I create this "View" link dynamically to carry the function call?

I have been using the `<a>` tag as standard html markup to call functions with success. It doesn't work if added dynamically for some reason:

```
<a href="#" runat="server" onserverclick="getFunction" style="text-decoration: none;">VIEW</u></a>
```

Is there another way to this?

EDIT:
The list items are html markup that displays the content on the page. Here's an example:

```
myList.Add(new ListObjectFunction("...content here...", <a href=\"#\" runat=\"server\" onserverclick=\"getMyFunction\" style=\"text-decoration: none; color: #FF6600;\">&nbsp;View&nbsp;</a>");
```

On the webpage, VIEW is a link that calls a function on the code behind page to display more content. The `<a>` tag link call to the function does not work. I am looking for an alternative to this.

Comment: `On the page, the contents of the list are displayed when a linkbutton is clicked. Each list item is displayed as a row with a "VIEW" link. `
How are you generating this code dynamically?

Comment: @SorangwalaAbbasali I have updated the question with an example of the html markup in the list item. myList is a list of tuples that calls a function to store these as ListObjectFunction objects. These are displayed from the aspx.cs page through a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

when(just before) adding the linkButton dynamically, write following code:

```
lnkBtn.Attributes.Add("click", "getFunction");
```

Comment: I updated the question with an example of the list item that contains html markup. Can you see how to create the linkbutton in the example?

Comment: Seems ListObjectFunction is your custom defined type. Can't help without knowing its details. Is there as chance to share complete code

Comment: No. You shouldn't need it. In the update you'll see that the list contains tuples. Just need to replace the <a> tag with something that works.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
lnkBtn.Attributes.Add("click", "getFunction()");
```